# Count subsets consisting strictly k elements

Tags: arrays, math, dynamic-programming, subset-sum, integer-partition

I want to count the subsets of `a` with `k` subset elements which sum to `n`. The possible subset elements are defined through a given array `a` with distinct positive elements. Possible subset elements can be just choosen once per subset.  How Can i do this? Optimal without iterating through all subsets.

Example:

`n := 10`

`k := 3`

`a := 1,2,6,7,8`

`=> 1 ( 1,2,7 )`

Comment: Seems you already know about dynamic programming. So apply it. Your last questions resemble homeworks without any attempts to solve.

Comment: *branch-and-bound* Dead easy.  But make sure you start at the large end of `a` so you can take full advantage of what you know about its contents.  That is, given that the largest element is `8` and that all elements are distinct and positive, the sum of the two smallest elements is at least `3`.

Comment: Yes but then iam kind of iterating through the combinations which is roughly O(n^k or k^n?). I through it can be solved with better complexity.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, horrid complexity.  In practice, it's generally a different matter but exactly how different depends on the examples you have to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a table `A` of size `(n+1)*(k+1)` or map with pair of integers as key.

Entry `A[i][j]` will contain number of variants to make sum `i` from `j` elements

You need to compose value n from k elements, so `A[n][k]` might be built from `A[n-v][k-1]` where `v` is any value from given set.

After filling the table `A[n][k]` is answer

Comment: This is what I consider a good answer for a question like this -- sketching the solution and the important points, and not spelling it all out.